# Why jenkins over simple bash scripts?

Tags: bash, git, jenkins, devops

I'd be really happy if you could just make me understand this easy topic.

I know what jenkins is and what it does.  Let's now make the comparison.

We use jenkins so that as soon as code gets pushed to repository, by git hooks, we run jenkins job which pull that code, make the build, run tests, and then if needed, upload it to remote machine where the code actually runs.

Now, what I can do instead is when git hook happens, I will run the bash script and that bash script will do the things(like pulling code from repository, running build, making test and then uploading it to remote machine via ssh).

So,I can do the same thing via bash script.

**Question is** : I don't see that much big of advantage.

So,could you do your best and explain in very simple terms why this has a big advantage ? I know there are many plugins for Jenkins, but this is not the way to make the comparison best way.

Comment: Not a good response. I will have the deployment script on remote machine and it will take care of everything as soon as git hook gets executed

Comment: You may not see much added value in using Jenkins over a bash script. I know people who drive thirty year old cars with fuel gauges that no longer work. Those cars still technically get you from place to place, so those people too may not see the added value in a modern vehicle. That being said, if you ask anything beyond the minimum of the vehicle then, much like the bash script, your mileage may vary as they say (pun unintended). Analogously, the bash script approach would not be feasible in a Production or Enterprise environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This explains the why we should avoid scripts and look for tooling. Moreover Jenkins and similar tooling provides standard ways to handle such deployments problems.

When development begins on a new software project, it is often a popular choice to script many of the steps of the continuous integration (CI) process. As the project grows to require a more complex infrastructure, unit and end-to-end testing, and a robust, repeatable deployment procedure, simple scripts are no longer the best solution.

To save a large hit on productivity, a better alternative is to replace these scripts with a Jenkins build server and a pipeline onfiguration.

**When it’s Time to Replace Scripts**

There are a few obvious signs that it might be time to replace scripted deployment methods with something a little more robust.

**When It Doesn’t Scale:** For every new piece added to an application, the scripts have to be updated. Whether you’re using bash, python, or something else, this can get out of hand quickly. Every line of code added to put new files in different locations, update permissions, and restart processes create more complexity and a greater risk of something going wrong.

**When It Becomes Unmaintainable:** The increasing complexity, from things like the addition of conditional logic to alter the deployment based on the state of the system, inevitably leads to a set of scripts that only a handful of developers can interpret. A process like this that grows organically to quickly meet the immediate needs of deploying the application creates a big problem.

**When It Gets Expensive:** In this case, the expense comes in the form of developer hours and productivity. The overhead required by the manual processes involved in preparing for and executing a release will begin to have a significant negative impact on new feature development.

Source:https://www.bandwidth.com/blog/replacing-scripted-software-deployments-jenkins-pipeline/

Comment: The funny thing is that you all say that for every piece added to an application, scripts have to be updated. Jenkins won't do it automatically unless you change it too. Jenkins is also used to run bash scripts. What you wrote as an answer is not practical at all. Provide just examples why it would make using bash scripts harder and we can argue about that.

Comment: In Jenkins also you have to add those changes manually. But can't you see this as the organized way to deal with the common deployment problems?.
Think from an operational point of view, maintaining many bash-script per project with common git flow changes and some project specific change in scripted format is easy or in plugin format it is easy?
**In the case of teammate change how easy this knowledge transformation process and dependency reduction Reading someone else script from scratch and understanding is not that easy but Jenkins like the plugin-based solution will make it easy**.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins probably works best when the project is structured along standard lines (as the most vanilla example take a Makefile/gcc project on Linux with a git repo).

For such a project Jenkins can be set up with a few steps to automatically check out, build, test and document these tests. A DIY approach would just re-invent the wheel.

If, on the other hand, the project has lots of unusual tools, mixes cygwin/POSIX things with Windows tools and relies on a lot of legacy scripting to glue things together the Jenkins workflow must be customized. Significant groovy code has to be maintained to call the idiosyncratic mix of bash, perl, and cmd scripts, some with Windows and some with POSIX command line syntax, strip away carriage returns from ClearCase outputs, move tool artifacts around and what not. That could perhaps be done as well with manual scripting. Jenkins still has an edge here though from the user perspective because of its built-in web interface. For example it provides forms to parametrize builds and provides a graphical overview of scheduled, running or finished jobs with links.

There may be another advantage to Jenkins when it comes to distributing the workload to several machines for which [Jenkins has built-in support](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds).